# what is the use of xterm in Ubuntu?

Tags: xterm

I am bit confused as in terminal window I typed `xterm` in Ubuntu it simply opened new terminal window `xterm` but was doing the same work as the default.

And its also mentioned this terminal is for the X Window.

But when I am typing window commands its not working. What I am missing. Please guide.

Comment: What is "window commands"?

Comment: @A.B. I thin OP means the right click feature. Which at least on my machine is Ctrl+Left Click.

Comment: Functionality of xterm is same because of the same shell by the way, like i mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 6):

The **xterm package** has been around since before the original days of `X Window`, a popular display server.

xterm **doesn’t require many resources (such as memory)** to operate. Because of this, the xterm package is still popular in Linux distributions designed to run on older hardware.

It can also **emulate older terminals**, such as  VT102,VT220, and Tektronix 4014 terminals (these are the terminals `used in 1980-1990's`).

To emulate VT100 terminal ,simply type

```
xterm -ti vt100
```

Answer (score 2):

By definition `xterm is a terminal emulator for the X Window System`. Since Ubuntu by default relies on X11 graphical server for any graphics - that's why `xterm` comes with Ubuntu. Now, unless you manually change it, both default terminal and `xterm` should run your `bash` shell, which is what actually interprets commands. Without shell, terminal emulator is basically not going to work.

`xterm` actually is the original terminal emulator and many modern emulators strive to emulate its functionality and extend it.